Perform transform on svg viewbox
I have a need to scale SVG's using javascript. This is part of a workflow so I'll be processing these endlessly in a browser.
The issue is the incoming SVG's viewbox is 0,0,14032.00mm,9922.00mm which is an aspect ratio to A4 paper. I need to scale the SVG down to 0,0,297.00mm,210.00mm without cropping the elements, they should also scale to remain within the viewbox.
Once they are scaled I can determine the scale factor and correctly adjust the stroke-widths — this much works already.  However, my math breaks down quite badly with the bezier elements. I frequently run into NaN errors. I'm wondering if I'm over thinking this and there is maybe an easier way to scale that individually scaling every single element...
This is not about scaling the viewbox to fit on screen, that's not my issue.
I was wondering if there was a simple way to perform a transform matrix or transform scale on the viewbox itself. I have not been able to find an answer because all the questions are about scaling the viewbox to the browser element container which is not what I need.
If I can scale the viewbox directly it may allow me to create a loop to apply the matrix to all elements?

Please include a minimal reproducible example. Quite likely, the error is caused by an invalid viewBox - it must not include any units otherwise the browser will use the fallback 300x150. Provided the graphics in the SVG fit the aspect ratio you only need to change the width of the svg. Changing the viewBox will result in cropping. See codepen example

If you really need to convert all values to "hardbaked" ones according to the scaling factor you may have a look at this post "Baking transforms into SVG Path Element commands" but frankly this can be quite tricky depending on the SVG's complexity

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
